# Which image file to pick for ddrescue?

Tags: ubuntu, ddrescue

The instructions for ddrescue / gddrescue are awful. The main instructions just say without mentioning any file types

> ddrescue /input /output logfile

Others tell me to do

> ddrescue /input /output.dmg logfile.log

I'm running Ubuntu 14 and I don't even know how to open and browse a .dmg file. I want to be able to open it like a .zip or .rar file and just browse around and look at the contents while it is in the process of completing. The .dmg file is currently 300GB and it's a 500GB drive.

Comment: gddrescue over ddrescue. .dmg is a apple specific extension. Extensions don't matter. Due to the nature of ddrescue's imaging, its not a stream, so opening it up while its doing its thing is unlikely.

Comment: There's no way for me to browse the files contained in the partially complete image file? The image file may *never* be complete because the drive itself is screwed.

Answer (score 1):

You want gddrescue - its a different package and better.

The syntax is simply `ddrescue source destination`

Assuming you want to backup `/dev/sda` its `ddrescue /dev/sda /path/to/file/filename.extension`

You can't peer into a gddrescue backup due to the way it backs up IIRC. Just let it do its thing.

Comment: That's what I've been using: http://mirror.lagoon.nc/pub/gnu/ddrescue/

Comment: What kind of file does gddrescue back up to? In Windows for example you've got ISO, zip, rar, etc. They're all different kinds of files read by different software but I can peer inside them and extract singular files any time I want. You're saying that I can simply do /path/to/file/filename.zip?

Comment: FYI I'm using version 1.21

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny What kind of file? `ddrescue` writes exact copy of the source, unless there are read errors. Even then it tries to save as much as possible. There is no specific format: zip in, zip out; ISO in, ISO out; device in, its image out – and so on.

Comment: Which file extension should I be picking then if I want to easily be able to mount the file in Ubuntu afterwards and get files off of it?

Comment: Extensions don't matter. Pick any or none.